# I do not see the sentence in the intended font

Tags: html, fonts, font-face

```
<html>

<head>
<title> </title>

<body>
    <font face="file:///E:/softwares/FONTS/alpha kufi regular.ttf" size="+2"> This is a tester for a font, that may not be installed on the machine </font>
</body>

</head>

</html>
```

This snippet doesn't show up the sentence in the intended font. What could be the reason for this ?

*Note: I am aware that the font tag is not supported by HTML 5 and deprecated by HTML 4.*

Comment: would you mind using google's font API?

Comment: @PankitKapadia No. But I would like to see an answer in a way I am looking for.

Comment: okei ! would like to know the answer in the way u looking for !! :)

Comment: @PankitKapadia I mean displaying the words in a font that is not installed on the machine.So I was trying to keep those fonts in a separate directory

Comment: ya i understand what you looking for but i also would like to know the good solution then using API !! :)

Comment: @PankitKapadia can you post your google's font API answer

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21766/discussion-between-pankit-kapadia-and-saplingpro)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two basic problems here: the HTML `face` attribute (as well as its CSS counterpart, the `font-family` property) needs a font family *name* as value, not a URL of a font file, and a `file:` URL is inherently system-dependent and may fail to work in many circumstances.

The following works, provided that the font file `alpha_kufi_regular.ttf` (better avoid spaces in font names, as spaces as such are disallowed in URLs) is placed in the `fonts` subdirectory of the directoty where you have the CSS file and the browser supports TrueType fonts as “web fonts” (this need not be “web font” usage but could be local; the techniques are the same):

```
<style>
@font-face {
    font-family: AlphaKufi;
    src: url('fonts/alpha_kufi_regular.ttf');
}
    </style>
<font face="AlphaKufi" size="+2"> This is a tester for a font, 
that may not be installed on the machine </font>
```

Since not all browsers support TrueType fonts as “web fonts”, consider using [FontSquirrel @font-face generato](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator)r if you intend to use the font on a web page.

It is usually better to use CSS rather than HTML for font settings, but that’s a different issue. In theory, “web fonts” need not work with HTML `<font face="...">` too (no specification requires that), but in practice they do.

Comment: I didn't know true type fonts and web fonts were different things.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find a reference for it, but my best guess is that you can't access fonts using the `file://` protocol (local filesystem). This is certainly true if the page is online or accessed through a local server (http://localhost or equivalent).

Also, there's no reason at all to ever use `<font>`. It might not work just because browsers don't support it fully anymore.

*edit*: in fact, I'm not sure `<font>` has ever supported using a font file instead of a font's name.

The solution for providing a font file is to use CSS's [`@font-face`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/@font-face).

Answer (score 0):

It's because `font`'s `face` attribute does not take a path to a font file. It takes a comma separated list of font names. The browser searches the system for installed fonts and loads the relevant one from there (if it exists).

If you want to specify your own, you will probably need to use [CSS @font-face](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/@font-face).

Answer (score 0):

Using Google Web Fonts API to add web fonts to your pages :

```
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=alpha kufi regular">
<style>
  body {
    font-family: 'alpha kufi regular';
    font-size: 48px;
  }
</style>
<title> </title>

<body>
    <div>This is a tester for a font, that may not be installed on the machine</div>
</body>

</head>

</html>
```

~ [Reference](https://developers.google.com/webfonts/docs/getting_started#Quick_Start)